# Validar campo nome - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Gostaria de saber como faço para validar um campo nome, para aceitar:

> - Letras (Maiúsculas e Minúsculas)
> - Números
> - Espaços
> - Máximo 30 caracteres
> - Não pode haver espaço duplo
> - Não pode haver espaço no início e no fim (Como no Fim o sobre nome terá que ter espaço, então não será necessário, pois validarei
>     com trim posteriormente)

**Código**

```
$("[name=nome_p]").keyup(function() {
        var $this = $( this ); //armazeno o ponteiro em uma variavel
        var valor = $this.val().replace(/[^a-z0-9 ]+/gi,'');
        $this.val( valor );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nos **inputs** use o atributo maxlength com valor igual a 30

```
<input type="text" maxlength="30" name="nome_p" value="" />
```

> para retirar espaços duplos no **script** acrescente

`valor = valor.replace(/( )+/g, ' ');`

```js
$("[name=nome_p]").keyup(function () { 
     var $this = $( this ); //armazeno o ponteiro em uma variavel
      var valor = $this.val().replace(/[^a-z0-9 ]+/gi,'');
      valor = valor.replace(/( )+/g, ' ');
      $this.val( valor );
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" maxlength="30" name="nome_p" value="" />
```

> Outra opção no **script** acrescente

`while (valor.indexOf('  ') != -1) valor = valor.replace('  ', ' ');`

```js
    $("[name=nome_p]").keyup(function () { 
     var $this = $( this ); //armazeno o ponteiro em uma variavel
      var valor = $this.val().replace(/[^a-z0-9 ]+/gi,'');
      while (valor.indexOf('  ') != -1) valor = valor.replace('  ', ' ');
      $this.val( valor );
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" maxlength="30" name="nome_p" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Expressão regular

```
/^[a-z\d](?:[a-z\d]| (?! |$)){0,29}$/i
```

**Significado**

- `^` - [Circunflexo](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/circunflexo.html#2_3_1) que casa o começo da cadeia de caracteres.
- `[a-z\d]` - [Lista](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/lista.html#2_1_2) que casa uma letra ou um número (para não permitir espaços no início).
- `(?:[a-z\d]| (?! |$)){0,29}` - Este é um [grupo](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/modernosos-fantasma.html#3_5_2) que é repetido entre 0 a 29 vezes, casando um caracter das duas [alternativas](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/ou.html#2_4_2):

  - `[a-z\d]` - letra ou número.
  - `(?! |$)` - espaço que não é seguido por outro espaço ou o fim da cadeia (usa um [*lookahead negativo*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).
- `$` - Fim da cadeia.
- `/i` - maiúsculas e minúsculas.

**Exemplo**

```js
$(function() {
    let er = /^[a-z\d](?:[a-z\d]| (?! |$)){0,29}$/i;
    
    $("#nome_p").on("input", function() {
        if (er.test($(this).val())) {
            // ✔️ válido
            $(this).removeClass("invalido");
        } else {
            // ✖️ inválido
            $(this).addClass("invalido");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
input.invalido:focus {
    border: 2px dashed red;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAJqp.png);
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" id="nome_p" name="nome_p">
```

---

#### Atributo pattern em HTML5 (sem Javascript)

Em HTML5 você pode usar o atributo [**pattern**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern) de um elemento <input> <sup>(Veja a [**compatibilidade**](http://caniuse.com/#search=pattern))</sup>.

```
<input pattern="Expressão regular" title="mensagem de erro">
```

**Código**

```css
input[type="text"]:required:invalid,
input[type="text"]:focus:invalid {
    border: 2px dashed red;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAJqp.png);
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input[type="text"]:valid {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6zP2.png);
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Nome" 
           pattern="[A-Za-z\d](?:[A-Za-z\d]| (?! |$)){0,29}" 
           title="• Letras&#10;• Números&#10;• Espaços&#10;• Máximo 30 caracteres&#10;• Não pode haver espaço duplo&#10;• Não pode haver espaço no início e no fim" 
           required
           >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Para limitar o tamanho use o atributo `maxlength="30"` da tag `input`, para remover os espaços no começo e no final da string é melhor você usar uma função `trim` no lado servidor ou onde seja que você recebe esse dado, e para permitir apenas os caracteres que você descreveu é melhor usar a função `keypress` e retornar false caso não atenda as suas condições.

Acredito que algo parecido com isso possa ajudar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[name=nome_p]").keypress(function(e) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (!/[a-z0-9 ]+/gi.test(char)) {
      return false;
    }

    if (value.substr(value.length - 1) === ' ') {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="nome_p" maxlength="30" />
```